# react native parse Promise object

Tags: react-native

i have problem return object , i call to test function from b.js but i cant 
read how i can this function and parse ? ,  pls help me

```
//a.js 

export async function test(){
try{
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user");
    return value ;
}
catch(e){
    console.log('error', e);
}

}
```

i want to parse aa  for example aa.id or  aa.name

```
//b.js 
import {test } from '../a.js';
  const aa = test() ; 
alert(aa); //aa = Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to await at b.js as well. Something like this will work.

```
const aa = async () => {
return await test()
}
```